# masonry style for posts unsuccessful

Tags: html, css

I tried in many ways to create masonry style for my posts, though the only way it works almost perfectly is the float:left. but sometimes there is a gap between them appearing, I'm looking for a good solution for this issue, there wise I'm adding my css and html so far.

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/ariefroni/gd9nna8m/4/embed/"></script>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ariefroni/gd9nna8m/4/

any solution to my problem is welcome, thanks.
also I don't mind be using script if need so.

Answer (score 2):

To create a masonry layout we can make use of the CSS properties `column-count` and `column-gap` which are applied to the parent element to determine the number of columns in your layout:

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
```

you then need to apply this style to each child:

```
.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[this tutorial](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) will show you exactly how to create masonry-style layouts. [Here's what you'll end up with](http://w3bits.com/labs/css-masonry/).

The demo markup is as follows:

```
<div class="masonry">
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
   <div class="item">Neque, vitae, fugiat, libero corrupti officiis sint facilis tempora quidem repudiandae praesentium odit similique adipisci aut.</div>
   <div class="item">Incidunt sit unde minima in nostrum?</div>
   <div class="item">Ducimus, voluptates, modi, delectus animi maiores consequuntur repellat quisquam fugiat eum possimus enim culpa totam praesentium magni quae!</div>
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dicta dolore adipisci hic ipsam velit deleniti possimus cumque accusantium rerum quibusdam.</div>
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, praesentium consequatur ducimus commodi quam ex illo omnis dicta reiciendis vel nesciunt deserunt aut sequi nam mollitia perferendis ipsam possimus temporibus!</div>
   <div class="item">Ab, adipisci, temporibus eaque quis harum perferendis incidunt cupiditate doloribus dolor numquam voluptates ipsum dolore aspernatur et voluptate ipsam beatae animi culpa.</div>
</div>
```

The tutorial also provides a link to a [JS fallback](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for older browsers

and that's all you need to create a Masonry-style layout :)

Comment: the only problem now is the order of things. the left line present the updated stuff while the right line is presenting the older stuff it has to go like 12, 34, 56 and not 14,25,36

Comment: can you elaborate?